# Check class instance passed to another module is of type class

Tags: python, class, types, instance

How to check type of class instance object passed from another module. Does it require `from main import MyClass`? Or can I just generally check object is of type "(any) class instance"?

```
# main.py
#########

import sub

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.z = 1

a = MyClass()
assert type(a) == MyClass
assert isinstance(a, MyClass) == True

b = sub.fun(a)



# sub.py
########

def fun(i):
    if isinstance(i, class):  # general instead of __main__.MyClass
        return i.__dict__
```

The above yields

```
NameError: name 'class' is not defined
```

Maybe it is not a good design and code shall be explicit rather than converting each class to dict?

Comment: what do you want to check with `if isinstance` ? Everything is a class..

Comment: @balderman I want to convert each class instance passed to fun to dictionary in order to avoid avoid importing classes from main.py to sub.py and specifying them in isinstance. Maybe more explicit design is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to convert each class instance passed to fun to dictionary

Try the below

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


def fun(instance):
    if hasattr(instance, '__dict__'):
        return instance.__dict__


print(fun(Foo(56)))
print(fun(Bar("56")))
```

output

```
{'x': 56}
{'x': '56'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  python needs to know which class you are checking because you can have two different classes with the same name in different files.

In file `sub.py` you have to write:

```py
from main import MyClass

def fun(i):
    if isinstance(i, MyClass): 
        return i.__dict__
```

But in case you importing `fun` into `main.py` you will get circular import, be careful)

Comment: At the end the cleanest. I am indeed getting a circular import.

Answer (score 0):

```python
# sub.py
########

def fun(i):
    if isinstance(i, class): # <---- class is keyword in Python, you cannot use it 
                             #       like this. You can use as type(class)
        return i.__dict__
```